My Arduino guitar tuner doesn't work with FFT
I make tuner on arduino. The FFT part and "work with frequency" part work good separately. But when i combined them on the lcd there is just showing blinking plus in the right bottom corner of the screen. But when i turn off FFT.Compute and FFT.ComplexToMagnitude funcs, everything works fine, except for FFT.
Code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <arduinoFFT.h>

#define SAMPLES 128
#define SAMPLING_FREQUENCY 1024

arduinoFFT FFT = arduinoFFT();

unsigned int samplingPeriod;
unsigned long microSeconds;

double vReal[SAMPLES];
double vImag[SAMPLES];

// Настройка дисплея
const uint8_t PIN_RS = 6;
const uint8_t PIN_EN = 7;
const uint8_t PIN_DB4 = 8;
const uint8_t PIN_DB5 = 9;
const uint8_t PIN_DB6 = 10;
const uint8_t PIN_DB7 = 11;

const int mic_pin = A5;

const uint8_t but_min_pin = 2; 
const uint8_t but_plus_pin = 3;

LiquidCrystal lcd(PIN_RS, PIN_EN, PIN_DB4, PIN_DB5, PIN_DB6, PIN_DB7);

// Установка частот для нот
const double Cfreqs[]        = {0.00, 32.70, 65.41, 130.82, 261.63, 523.25, 1046.50, 2093.00, 4186.00};
const double Csharpfreqs[]   = {0.00, 34.65, 69.30, 138.59, 277.18, 554.36, 1108.70, 2217.40, 4434.80};
const double Dfreqs[]        = {0.00, 36.95, 73.91, 147.83, 293.66, 587.32, 1174.60, 2349.20, 4698.40};
const double Dsharpfreqs[]   = {0.00, 38.88, 77.78, 155.56, 311.13, 622.26, 1244.50, 2489.00, 4978.00};
const double Efreqs[]        = {20.61, 41.21, 82.41, 164.81, 329.63, 659.26, 1318.50, 2637.00, 5274.00};
const double Ffreqs[]        = {21.82, 43.65, 87.31, 174.62, 349.23, 698.46, 1396.90, 2793.80, 0.00};
const double Fsharpfreqs[]   = {23.12, 46.25, 92.50, 185.00, 369.99, 739.98, 1480.00, 2960.00, 0.00};
const double Gfreqs[]        = {24.50, 49.00, 98.00, 196.00, 392.00, 784.00, 1568.00, 3136.00, 0.00};
const double Gsharpfreqs[]   = {25.95, 51.90, 103.80, 207.00, 415.30, 830.60, 1661.20, 3332.40, 0.00};
const double Afreqs[]        = {27.50, 55.00, 110.00, 220.00, 440.00, 880.00, 1720.00, 3440.00, 0.00};
const double Asharpfreqs[]   = {29.13, 58.26, 116.54, 233.08, 466.16, 932.32, 1864.60, 3729.20, 0.00};
const double Bfreqs[]        = {30.87, 61.74, 123.48, 246.96, 493.88, 987.75, 1975.50, 3951.00, 0.00};

const String noteNames[] = {"C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"};

const double* const allNotesFreqs[] = {Cfreqs, Csharpfreqs, Dfreqs, Dsharpfreqs, Efreqs, Ffreqs, Fsharpfreqs, Gfreqs, Gsharpfreqs, Afreqs, Asharpfreqs, Bfreqs};

double playedFreq;          // Значение частоты, которое будет считываться с джека
double freqScale = 440.00;  // Частота ноты A, которую можно регулировать потенциометром
String playedNote = "";     // Нота, которая будет определена
char symbol = ' ';          // Символ, который будет отображаться рядом с нотой

int minFlag, plusFlag;



double findDifference(double freq, const double *noteFreqs, double fscale) {
  double minDifference = 999999.99;
  double fmultiplier = 440.00 / fscale;
  freq = freq * fmultiplier;
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    double difference = fabs(noteFreqs[i] - freq);
    if (difference < minDifference) {
      minDifference = difference;
    }
  }
  return minDifference;
}

char findNoO(double freq, const double *noteFreqs, double fscale) {
  int NoO;
  double minDifference = 999999.99;
  double fmultiplier = 440.00 / fscale;
  freq = freq * fmultiplier;
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    double difference = fabs(noteFreqs[i] - freq);
    if (difference < minDifference) {
      minDifference = difference;
      NoO = i;
    }
  }
  return NoO;
}

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  samplingPeriod = round((float)1000000 / SAMPLING_FREQUENCY);
}

void loop() {
  for(int i = 0; i<SAMPLES; i++) {
    microSeconds = micros();

    vReal[i] = analogRead(A0);
    vImag[i] = 0;

    while(micros() < (microSeconds + samplingPeriod)) {
      // Ничего не делаем
    }
  }
  
  FFT.Windowing(vReal, SAMPLES, FFT_WIN_TYP_HAMMING, FFT_FORWARD);
  //FFT.Compute(vReal, vImag, SAMPLES, FFT_FORWARD);
  //FFT.ComplexToMagnitude(vReal, vImag, SAMPLES);

  double peak = FFT.MajorPeak(vReal, SAMPLES, SAMPLING_FREQUENCY) -7.5;
  
  playedFreq = peak;

  if (digitalRead(but_min_pin) == HIGH) {
        if (!minFlag) {
            freqScale = freqScale - 1;
            delay(10);
            minFlag = 1;
        }
    } 
    else {
        minFlag = 0;
    }
    if (digitalRead(but_plus_pin) == HIGH) {
        if (!plusFlag) {
          freqScale ++;
          delay(10);
          plusFlag = 1;
        }
    } 
    else {
        plusFlag = 0;
    }
  int noteNum = 0;
  double minDiff = 999999.99;
  while (noteNum < 12) {
    double currentDiff = fabs(findDifference(playedFreq, allNotesFreqs[noteNum], freqScale));
    if (currentDiff < minDiff) {
      minDiff = currentDiff;
      playedNote = noteNames[noteNum];
      if (playedFreq < allNotesFreqs[noteNum][findNoO(playedFreq, allNotesFreqs[noteNum], freqScale)]) {
        symbol = '-';
      }
      else if (playedFreq > allNotesFreqs[noteNum][findNoO(playedFreq, allNotesFreqs[noteNum], freqScale)]) {
        symbol = '+';
      }
      else {
        symbol = ' ';
      }
    }
    noteNum++;
  }

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(String(playedFreq) + "    " + freqScale);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);

  if (symbol == '+') {
    lcd.print("       " + playedNote);
    lcd.setCursor(11, 1);
    lcd.print("+");
  } else if (symbol == '-') {
    lcd.print("   -   " + playedNote);
    lcd.setCursor(11, 1);
    lcd.print(" ");
  } else {
    lcd.print("       " + playedNote);
    lcd.setCursor(11, 1);
    lcd.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println(analogRead(mic_pin));
} 

I wanted just to have working arduino gutar tuner.

It is a bit too complicated to be an MRE. Your best bet for figuring out the FFT part is to find the maximum peak that isn't at the transform origin and display its index on your LCD. That will allow you to test if the FFT is behaving. You may also need a longer FFT that 128 samples to have anything like enough frequency resolution try it on 1024 or however many samples makes up 1s and it might then work. If the fft code supports it then real to complex conjugate symmetric transform is almost half the computational effort (no array of 0 imaginary components needed at all).
